# Adding and Subtracting numbers with exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is $2^{k+1} + 2^{k+1} = 2^{k+2}$ and not $4^{k+1}$

Comment: Let $k=1$. Why is $4+4=8$ and not $16$?

Answer (score 4):

Because
$$2^{k+1}+2^{k+1}=2^1\times 2^{k+1}=2^{1+(k+1)}=2^{k+2}.$$

Note that $$4^{k+1}=(2^2)^{k+1}=2^{2(k+1)}=2^{2k+2}.$$

Comment: would it matter if the base was 3

Comment: @wannabe_n00b: $3^{k+1}+3^{k+1}=2\cdot 3^{k+1}$.